# Slide/animate the Extjs window

Tags: extjs, jquery

I am using Geoext, OpenLayers and ExtJS. In toolbar button I have tried to show window on click using ExtJS. I now want to animate/slide this window  before appearing instead of directly appearing.

I also realized knowing jQuery is useful. But how should I implement the following code?

My code for the click is as follow:

```
mainWindow = new Ext.Window({
    title: 'Company Information',
    collapsible: true,
    maximizable: true,
    closeAction: 'close',
    renderTo:Ext.getBody(),
    //renderTo:"div",
    bodyStyle: 'padding:10 10px 5;',
    width: 696,
    height: 445,
    enableTabScroll : true,
    frame: true,
    // layout: 'fit',
    plain: true,
    bodyStyle: 'padding:10px;',
    buttonAlign: 'center',
    items: [gridPanel],
});

mainWindow.show();
```

Can any one please help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look in Ext FX and Ext Element (http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.Element)